# PHP PDO access database with wrong username

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm writing an application using PHP, to test database connection using PDO and just querying "SHOW DATABASES".
However if I try to connect to database with an unexisting user I get connection as well...

for example if I try this, with the correct user (root):

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', 'root', '');
$result = $conn->query("SHOW DATABASES");
while($row = $result->fetchAll()){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

and echo the result I get this:

```
array(5) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Database"]=> string(18) "information_schema" [0]=> string(18) "information_schema" } [1]=> array(2) { ["Database"]=> string(5) "mysql" [0]=> string(5) "mysql" } [2]=> array(2) { ["Database"]=> string(18) "performance_schema" [0]=> string(18) "performance_schema" } [3]=> array(2) { ["Database"]=> string(10) "phpmyadmin" [0]=> string(10) "phpmyadmin" } [4]=> array(2) { ["Database"]=> string(4) "test" [0]=> string(4) "test" } }
```

however if I use a random string for the username, like this:

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', 'sdghasdgas', '');
$result = $conn->query("SHOW DATABASES");
while($row = $result->fetchAll()){
    var_dump($row);
}
```

I still get results but only this:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["Database"]=> string(18) "information_schema" [0]=> string(18) "information_schema" } [1]=> array(2) { ["Database"]=> string(4) "test" [0]=> string(4) "test" } }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you should check the privileges for test - probably it is allowing every connection without authentification.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann but i'm not querying any specific database

Comment: you are querying information_schema, which shows all available databases. if test is publicly accessible, it will turn up in information_schema.